# How to query XML in T-SQL with inline ID

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

I have this XML stored in a record, how can I get a value of a specific ID?

```
<Attributes>
<CustomerAttribute ID="4">
    <CustomerAttributeValue>
        <Value>1</Value>
    </CustomerAttributeValue>
</CustomerAttribute>
<CustomerAttribute **ID="5"**>
    <CustomerAttributeValue>
        <Value>**aaaaa**</Value>
    </CustomerAttributeValue>
</CustomerAttribute>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow What have you tried so far? Have you had a look at [XQUERY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/xquery/xquery-language-reference-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)? SO isn't a free coding service, so please show us your attempts first, and we can show you where you went wrong. thanks.

Comment: Did you add that ** around ID 5 ?  If not this would not be valid XML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the `**` surrounding `ID="5"` and "aaaaa" denotes the nodes you want to select, below is one method.

```
SELECT XmlColumn.value('(/Attributes/CustomerAttribute[@ID="5"]/CustomerAttributeValue/Value)[1]', 'varchar(100)')
FROM  dbo.xml
WHERE XmlColumn.exist('/Attributes/CustomerAttribute[@ID="5"]') = 1;
```

This assumes the actual XML value is like:

```
<Attributes>
    <CustomerAttribute ID="4">
        <CustomerAttributeValue>
            <Value>1</Value>
        </CustomerAttributeValue>
    </CustomerAttribute>
    <CustomerAttribute ID="5">
        <CustomerAttributeValue>
            <Value>aaaaa</Value>
        </CustomerAttributeValue>
    </CustomerAttribute>
</Attributes>
```